# How to assure that the Express response comes after the File System terminates the write stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, fs

In an Express.js API I'm creating a zip file that stores a collection of PDFs that is intended to be passed as a download

I have created the zipfile using the [yazl](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yazl) package following the README file, and it's pretty good, the problem comes when I use the pipe to create the **createWriteStream**, because I don't know how to properly wait until is finished.

Then in my Express route I want to send the file, but this code is executed before the write stream is finished...

This is a piece of code of a Promise function named **renderReports** inside my **repository.js** file, after I write the PDFs file I use a loop to added to the yazl's zipFile, then I proceed to create the zip with the `fs.createWriteStream`

```
const renderFilePromises = renderResults.map((renderedResult, index) =>
  writeFile(`./temporal/validatedPdfs/${invoices[index].id}.pdf`, renderedResult.content)
);
await Promise.all(renderFilePromises);
const zipfile = new yazl.ZipFile();
invoices.map((invoice, index) => {
  zipfile.addFile(`./temporal/validatedPdfs/${invoice.id}.pdf`, `${invoice.id}.pdf`)
});
zipfile.outputStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./temporal/output.zip").on('close', () => {
  console.log('...Done');
}));
zipfile.end();
resolve();
```

And the following code is how I use the promise

```
app.post('/pdf-report', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { invoices } = req.body;
  repository.renderReports(reporter, invoices)
    .then(() => {
      res.sendFile('output.zip', {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, './../../temporal/'),
        dotfiles: 'deny',
      }, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(err.status).end();
      }
      else {
        console.log('Sent:', 'output.zip');
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((renderErr) => {
    console.error(renderErr);
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return res.status(501).send(renderErr.message);
  });
});
```

I hope somebody can explain how to approach this

Comment: Probably you can use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) for that.

Comment: Actually I tried promisfying the writeStream, but I did not succeed I don't know why... because then Postman could not get response on the server, so If you could post some code to figure out how to approach this problem, would be nice

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the write stream in a variable so you can access it. Then, on this variable, wait for the stream‘s finish event. This is emitted by Node.js once the stream is done with writing.

Comment: I don't want to bother you, but if you could put some code would be nice, I tried to do it mostly how you explained to me, but then I got no response on the server using Postman